# How to access a property of an object stdClass Object?

Tags: object, stdclass

Doing print_r() on my array I get the following:

```
                stdClass Object
           (
[Products] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Id] => 265531
                [ProductTitle] => test0
                [ZarfiyatSalane] => 600.000
                [MizanJazbMavad] => 660.000
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [Id] => 265532
                [ProductTitle] => test1
                [ZarfiyatSalane] => 500.000
                [MizanJazbMavad] => 500.000
            )

    )

)
```

How can I access a specific value in the array?
 The following code does not work because of the stdClass Object

```
echo $array['ProductTitle'];
```

Comment: What code doesn't work?

Comment: echo $array['ProductTitle'];

Comment: You're working with objects, so presumably it would be `$object->ProductTitle`, or maybe `$array[0]->ProductTitle` if you're working with an array of objects.

Comment: $test = $res->GetLicenseInfoByIdentCodeResult->LicenseInfo->Products ; 
Doing :
print_r($test) ; 
Like above 
but command The following code does not work : 
echo $test->ProductTitle ;

Comment: It looks like $test is an array of objects, not a single object.

Comment: Thank you .  I converted  into an array and then resolved with this command :
echo $object['Products'][0]->ProductTitle